# Count the number of times a date is contained between 2 date columns

Tags: sql-server

I have a table that looks like this

```
ID  start_dt    end_dt
--------------------------
1   1951-12-05  1951-12-21
2   1951-12-19  1951-12-31
3   1957-12-05  1957-12-19
4   1995-12-06  1995-12-20
5   1996-06-24  1996-07-08
6   1997-05-12  1997-05-26
7   1997-10-07  1997-10-21
8   1997-12-25  1998-01-08
9   1998-01-19  1998-02-02
10  1998-08-05  1998-08-19
```

I'd like to know how many times each individual date is contained between `start_dt` and `end_dt`.

From my example, the result set should look something like this

```
date         count
------------------
1951-12-05   1
1951-12-06   1
...
1951-12-19   2
1951-12-20   2
1951-12-21   2
...
1998-08-19   1
```

What would be the best way to do this?

EDIT:  To clarify, I need each date that appears at least once in a date range (between start_dt and end_dt) to get a row in my result set and I want the number of ranges that this date fits in next to it

hope this helps

Comment: This question isn't clear. "each invidiual date", where did 1951-12-06 come from? Are you saying that you want "each date from lowest start_dt up to highest end_dt, for each such date, count how many intervals (start_dt - end_dt) that would cover it in my table", is that it?

Comment: why do you have a count of 2 for 1951-12-19?

Comment: Because it's the end date of row 1 and the start date of row 2?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen almost, I don't want the count only for start_dt dates and end_dt dates but for all the dates in between also.  In my example, I have a row for the date 1951-12-06 even though it's not in either of my fields

Comment: @Eric like ChrisF said

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there are no more than a few days (< 80 or so, depending in your `sys.objects` table) between `start_dt` and `end_dt`, you can use this approach (inspired on Rhys').

```
DECLARE @dates TABLE (id int not null, start_dt date not null, end_dt date not null)
INSERT @dates VALUES
    (1, '1951-12-05', '1951-12-21'),
    (2, '1951-12-19', '1951-12-31'),
    (3, '1957-12-05', '1957-12-19'),
    (4, '1995-12-06', '1995-12-20'),
    (5, '1996-06-24', '1996-07-08'),
    (6, '1997-05-12', '1997-05-26'),
    (7, '1997-10-07', '1997-10-21'),
    (8, '1997-12-25', '1998-01-08'),
    (9, '1998-01-19', '1998-02-02'),
    (10, '1998-08-05', '1998-08-19');

WITH RawData AS (
SELECT  
    DATEADD(d, n.n, d.start_dt) AS [date]
FROM @dates d
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY object_id) - 1 AS n FROM sys.objects
    ) n ON DATEADD(d, n.n, d.start_dt) <= d.end_dt
)
SELECT [date], COUNT(*) [count]
FROM RawData
GROUP BY [date]
ORDER BY [date]
```

I don't think this could take long even with 1000 date ranges. Perhaps you are using a table with more fields and even missing some index?

Comment: this is great, it runs in under 1 sec with my 1000 rows sample.

Comment: What's the maximum span in days between start and end dates? If it happens to be more than the rowcount of sys.objects, this may skip some days.

Comment: shouldn't be more than 14 days

Answer (score 1):

When you need to turn 2 values (a range) into a series of rows you can use a number table (see Aaron Bertrand's [The SQL Server Numbers Table](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4176/the-sql-server-numbers-table-explained--part-1/) article if you aren't familiar with the idea).

I've used shorter and simpler data but you should get the idea.

```
declare @dates table (id int not null, start_dt date not null, end_dt date not null)
insert @dates values (1, '20160601', '20160603'),
                     (2, '20160603', '20160605'),
                     (3, '20160610', '20160612')

;with cte as (
    select
        row_number() over (order by so1.object_id) - 1 as n
    from
        sys.objects so1
            cross join sys.objects so2
)
select  
    dateadd(d, c.n, d.start_dt) as [date],
    count(*)
from
    @dates d
        join cte c on dateadd(d, c.n, d.start_dt) <= d.end_dt
group by 
    dateadd(d, c.n, d.start_dt)
order by 
    dateadd(d, c.n, d.start_dt)
```

Comment: thanks, this works, however I have a fairly large number of date ranges and this is a costly method.  using a sample of 1000 date ranges, it took 3 minutes to complete

Comment: That's a separate problem and could depend on many things outside the scope of the original question.

Comment: there's also the possibility that a better method exists, don't you think?

Comment: From the information provided this is a reasonable approach. If it takes over 3 minutes to run against 1000 rows then there's something significant you haven't mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a CTE

```
WITH CTE AS(SELECT start_dt AS dates FROM Table
            UNION ALL
            SELECT end_dt AS dates FROM Table)
SELECT CAST(dates as DATE) as Date, COUNT(dates) AS Count
FROM CTE c
GROUP BY c.dates
order by Count desc
```

Or perhaps you need something broader if your columns are of `DATETIME` data type. This way will `GROUP BY` the whole day:

```
WITH CTE AS(SELECT CAST(start_dt AS DATE) AS dates FROM Table
            UNION ALL
            SELECT CAST(end_dt AS DATE) AS dates FROM Table)
SELECT Dates as Date, COUNT(Dates) AS Count
FROM CTE c
GROUP BY c.dates
order by Count desc
```

Comment: this unfortunately doesn't work, maybe my question isn't clear enough. this just gives me the count for the values of the start_dt field and the end_dt, I need it to give me the count for all dates contained between start and end too

Comment: So if a date isn't listed in the table, you want a result set that will create a record for that date with a count of 1?

Comment: if it's not listed, but is contained in one or more of the start_dt/end_dt range, it should be displayed in the result set